# How to automatically set default-directory to projectile-project-root?

Tags: evil, projectile

emacs beginner here. I would like for the default-directory of any buffer that's part of a projectile project to be the project root. For example if I'm editing `include/my_file.hpp` and I do:

```
:e src/my_file.cpp
```

emacs will try and create `include/src/my_file.cpp`, which is obviously not what I want. Can I force emacs to use the project root dir as the default-directory? Maybe using a hook of some kind?